# Include the contents of other files when rendering jade in Express?

Tags: node.js, include, express, pug

I have the following layout.jade:

```
!!!
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body!= body
```

In the body, I'd like to include the contents of another file, content.jade.

I'm trying something like this in app.js:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
  res.render('layout', {
    layout: false,
    body: include content.jade
  });
});
```

but it gives SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at 'content'. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to render your content (body)  file, not the layout. With the layout: true param (which is the default, I think)  jade will automatically use layout.jade to render the "frame" of your page, and then feed your content in the body variable, passed to the layout ( see [Expres doc](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-rendering) ). so:

```
res.render('content');
```

should do the job.